# ¿Cómo establecer un archivo externo de css en un archivo html?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un archivo index, este archivo contiene algunos estilos, pero lo que quiero es poner un archivo externo, tengo conflicto en esto. Esta es la forma en la que lo establezco dentro del HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mapared.css">
```

No me da ningún error, pero algunos estilos que contiene este archivo no se vinculan, y cuando los tengo directamente desde el índex, si funciona correctamente.

Elimine el cache, pero sigue igual. Cualquier sugerencia de los agradezco.

Comment: Considera aportar un [mcve] que le permita a la comunidad replicar el problema que presenta tu código

Comment: Amigo considera dar más información ya que con eso no es posible o resulta muy difícil resolver tu duda

Comment: No se cual es tu directorio pero intenta con ./css/mapared.css

Answer (score 0):

Si solamente algunos estilos especificados dentro del fichero externo no se aplican en el html considera revisar que no existan los mismos estilos incrustados en la cabecera ya que mandarían estos últimos sobre los estilos del fichero externo.

Ejemplo del funcionamiento de la aplicación de estilos a continuación:

```css
p.rojo{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>  
      <title>Formas de integración de CSS en un documento HTML</title> 
     <style>
     p{
     color:blue;</style>
   </head> 
   <body>
   <h3>Estilo fichero externo</h3>
      <p class="rojo">Párrafo de color rojo.</p>
   <h3>Estilo incrustado en encabezado</h3>
      <p>Párrafo de color azul.</p>
   <h3>Estilo inline</h3>
      <p style="color:green;">Párrafo de color verde.</p>
   </body> 
</html>
```